# Login Facebook app with fb link at redirect_uri

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created a page tab app from developers so in the fields I have:

Canvas Url: http://ingersidemon.ro/proiecte/pitzi-world.ro/.facebook/concurs/

Secure Canvas Url: https://ingersidemon.ro/proiecte/pitzi-world.ro/.facebook/concurs/

Page Tab Url: http://ingersidemon.ro/proiecte/pitzi-world.ro/.facebook/concurs/

Secure Page Tab Url: https://ingersidemon.ro/proiecte/pitzi-world.ro/.facebook/concurs/

So the problem is: I want to create a login dialog something like this:

```
$dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=".$app_id."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($my_url)."&state=".$_SESSION['state']."&scope=publish_stream";
```

Where `$my_url = "http://www.facebook.com/1mil.Fotografii/app_415786855156952";`

It gives me error because the url is not own by the application settings, but at some apps source I see this Url with facebook link working. If i set

https://ingersidemon.ro/proiecte/pitzi-world.ro/.facebook/concurs/

After the login url my app wont open in Iframe mode, it opens the https://ingersidemon.ro/proiecte/pitzi-world.ro/.facebook/concurs/ not in facebook, where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your app does not own http://facebook.com domain, 
change $my_url to $my_url = 'http://ingersidemon.ro/proiecte/' ... where you can handle facebook response, check facebook api to see what facebook sends you back

Comment: This is response? $response = file_get_contents($dialog_url);

Comment: No, you can't do that, cause you don't want the content of that url. facebook dialog is page where user authorise your application to access his data

Comment: I dont find here how i get response http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/

Answer (score 0):

> Where $my_url = "http://www.facebook.com/1mil.Fotografii/app_415786855156952";
>
> It gives me error because the url is not own by the application settings

Since calling that URL in my browser only leads me to the page itself (same as if https://www.facebook.com/1mil.Fotografii was called directly), I suspect you either did not install this app on the page, or you might still have sandbox mode turned on in your app settings.